# How to sync transactions among two nodes in a Blockchain

Tags: azure, blockchain

I have a multinode blockchain in Azure.How can I sync the transactions between multiple nodes ?

Comment: On a blockchain the sync is done via consensus that create block to propagate to every node. It really depends by the protocol you are using, but I think that the sync action should not be triggered by an external program or a smart contract!

Comment: Ok so all of the sync action will be done by itself right that is the network should do all the action of syncing.

Comment: The sync of a valid transaction is done by adding it into a block that "by consensus" is propaated to all nodes. Then every protocols has its own implementation.